# Jupyter notebook display SAS output word-wrapper

Tags: sas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a table in sas format (.sas7bdat) and would like to output it in Jupyter notebook.

> proc print data=dataBoxE.my_data (firstobs=2 obs=12);
>   run;

The output table is jammed together since it has 100+ columns. How should I setup the environment within my notebook?

Moreover, is there a way to save the log file instead of opening it right away in the output cell? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In SAS you can change the location of where the log file is created using `proc printto`; Documentation [here](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n1oardywxmmut7n1pol0zkj5u1ok.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).

When using `proc printto`, don't forget to reset the location to the default system value at the end of your, Example:

```
proc printto log='c:\em\log1.log';
   run;
/* Your code here */
proc printto;
run;
```

If you don't need the 100+ columns; then select only the ones you want using the `VAR` statement in `proc print` Documentation [here](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n1h2bc0rkcufgwn11accg1uiksto.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) :

```
proc print data=exprev;
   var country price sale_type;
run;
```

If you want all the 100+; just export them to csv using `proc export` and view them in any spreadsheet reader to avoid crashing your browser. Documentation [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000316288.htm).

```
proc export data=sashelp.class
   outfile='c:\myfiles\Femalelist.csv'
   dbms=csv
   replace;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks @momo1644 for your prompt response. I have learned something new from your post. Even though, I still want to know whether I can display the wrapped 100+ sas table in Jupyter notebook without exporting to other data format or selecting some of the columns. Something similar can be done in python notebook with pandas function (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html).